# Snowflake: Does anyone have any idea that how to create a snowflake organization to organize all the snowflake accounts

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

can anyone explain the complete process to create a snowflake organization account and the way to attach/detach account from it? I looked into the snowflake console as well as in documentation but have not gotten clarity

Comment: In case you are looking for something like create organization statement, then I doubt if there is any. one can only add account to the organization via ORGADMIN role. Refer - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/organizations.html#organization-ddl.  ORGADMIN role is enabled by snowflake, refer - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/organizations-gs.html#enabling-the-orgadmin-role-for-an-account

Answer (score 1):

You should submit a ticket to Snowflake Support to enable organization on one of your accounts. This will create the ORGADMIN role in the account. Then you can grant this role to one of your users. The user which has the ORGADMIN role can access the Organization page. From the organization page, you can see your existing accounts, and create new accounts. When you create a new account, it will be in your organization automatically.

If you have an account which you can't see on the organization page, that means the account was created in another organization. In this case, you need to submit a ticket to Snowflake Support and ask them to move your account to your organization.

Normally, it's expected that each customer should have one organization, but if you have multiple organizations, you can also ask Snowflake Support to move your account from one organization to antother (that's how you would detach). If you want to drop an account, you should also contact Snowflake Support, it can't be done through the organization page.